# Algebraic or combinatorial proof that $(\sum_{n=0}^\infty {\frac{1}{m} \choose n} z^n )^m = 1+z$ as formal polynomials

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, power-series, formal-power-series

I know how to prove this using analytic techniques (just by using derivatives of $(1+z)^{\frac{1}{m}}$, and basic facts about power series), but I was wondering if there's any way to prove this using algebraic, or combinatorial techniques.

Comment: you mean a proof of the [binomial series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series) ? write the Taylor expansion of $f(z) = (1+z)^a$ around $z=0$ and show that for any $a \in \mathbb{R}$ (or $\mathbb{C}$) the radius of convergence is non-zero (it is $1$)

Comment: and no, since ${1/m \choose n}$ is defined by the $\Gamma$ function, you'll need some analytic proof.

Comment: @user1952009, I disagree with your second claim. We can write $\binom{\alpha}{m} = \alpha(\alpha-1)\cdots(\alpha-n+1)/n!$, which does not necessarily exclude combinatorial interpretation for $\alpha = 1/m$.

Comment: @SangchulLee : ok, so good luck for finding a combinatorial proof of the Taylor expansion theorem, of $e^x = \sum_{k=0}^\infty \frac{x^k}{k!}$ and many other analysis theorems ! :-)

Comment: @user1952009, Thank you. In fact, I am kind of on the track as you can see [*here*](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1729174/is-there-any-interesting-interpretation-of-taylor-coefficients-of-e-log1-x).