# $\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{\sum_{i=1}^n m_i = m, \\ m_i \in \mathbb N_+} \frac{1}{m_1\cdots m_n} = 1$?

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, integer-partitions

I found an equation accidentally when doing my research about [branching processes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branching_process). I think it is correct but I don't know how to prove it:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{n=1}^m \frac{1}{n!} \sum_{\sum_{i=1}^n m_i = m, \\ m_i \in \mathbb N_+} \frac{1}{m_1\cdots m_n} = 1, \quad m\in \mathbb N_+.
\end{equation}
I found it by enumeration by hand:

- $m=1$,
  $$\frac{1}{1!} \cdot \frac{1}{1} = 1.$$
- $m=2$,
  $$\frac{1}{1!} \cdot \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2!} \cdot \frac{1}{1\cdot 1} = \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{2} = 1.$$
- $m=3$,
  $$\frac{1}{1!} \cdot \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2!} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{1\cdot 2} \cdot 2 \right) + \frac{1}{3!} \cdot \frac{1}{1\cdot 1\cdot 1} = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{6} = 1.$$
- $m=4$,
  $$\frac{1}{1!} \cdot \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{2!} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{1\cdot 3} \cdot 2 + \frac{1}{2\cdot 2} \right) + \frac{1}{3!} \cdot \left( \frac{1}{2\cdot 1\cdot 1} \cdot 3 \right) + \frac{1}{4!} \cdot \frac{1}{1\cdot 1\cdot 1\cdot 1} = \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{8} + \frac{1}{4} + \frac{1}{24} = 1.$$
- ...

I tried $m$ until 5 and I was surprised that the equation holds for all of them. I think this is not a coincidence. I also tried to prove it by induction, but I don't know how to apply the inductive hypothesis.

I feel that this equation should relate to integer [partition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28number_theory%29) and [factorization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer_factorization), because the second summation is over partitions of $m$ and the product $m_1\cdots m_n$ is like a factorization of some integer.

But still, I have no idea to prove it. Have anyone seen it somewhere? Or does anyone know how to prove it? Any references or hints will be appreciated.

Comment: 3 hints: 1) your LHS is the coefficient of $x^m$ in
$\sum_{n=1}^m\frac{y^n}{n!},$ where $y=\sum_{k\ge1}\frac{x^k}k=-\ln(1-x).$ 2) It is the same as the coefficient in $\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{y^n}{n!}=e^y-1=\frac x{1-x}.$ 3) $\frac1{1-x}=\sum_{j\ge0}x^j.$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there any interesting interpretation of Taylor coefficients of $e^{-\log(1-x)}$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1729174/is-there-any-interesting-interpretation-of-taylor-coefficients-of-e-log1-x) found [using Approach$0$](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=AND%20site%3Amath.stackexchange.com%2C%20OR%20content%3A%24%5Csum_%7Bn%3D1%7D%5Em%5Cfrac%7B(%5Csum_%7Bk%5Cge1%7D%5Cfrac%7Bx%5Ek%7Dk)%5En%7D%7Bn!%7D%24&p=1)

Comment: @AnneBauval I have understood your elegant hints. Thank you very much, Anne, for your hints, and also for the link which explained exactly the equation I posted.